# Python New line in return from a function

Tags: python, function, return, line

I am new to python and faced the following problem.. I am trying to get from a function a text in two lines using return, but still getting "\n" as a text (in IDLE 3.5). All works fine when I change "return" to "print", but I need "return".

```
def myfunc(a):
    text1=["|"]
    i=int(a)
    mystr="abc|"*i+"\n"
    text1.append(mystr)
    text1=''.join(text1)
    b="0"
    text2=[b]
    for b in range(i):
        b+=1
        text2.append("{0:5d}".format(b))
    text1="".join((text1,"".join(text2)))
    return(text1)
```

result:

```
>>> myfunc(4)
'|abc|abc|abc|abc|\n0    1    2    3    4'
```

but

```
(...)
print(text1)
>>> myfunc(4)
abc|abc|abc|abc|
0    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how this works. `return` gives you the string literal. It *is* on two lines (e.g., if you print this out to a file object, or buffer, etc.).  WHen displayed in the console, it is not "formatted" nicely.

Comment: Just try `print(myfunc(4))` instead.

Comment: There is no issue here. The only difference is that in one case the value is formatted as a syntactically valid Python literal, and in the other case it is actually printed to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When entering an expression that returns a string in the interactive interpreter, you will be shown the *representation* of that string.  This is different from the *printing* the string, which will write the characters of the string itself directly to the terminal.

The representation generally tries to show the string in a format that Python would accept as a string literal, i.e. it is enclosed in quotes, and special characters are escaped, like you see for `\n`.